# como hago para obtener 10 posiciones diferentes en dos arreglos ---- lenguaje C

Tags: c++, array, c, random

estoy usando dos arreglos como eje X e Y  para un ejercicio, mis arreglos tienen 10 valores cada uno, randomizados por la funcion rand(), mi problema es que a veces los valores X e Y de las coordenadas de dos o tres numeros coincide, y necesito que esto no suceda, y se generen 10 valores exactamente distintos. dejo un ejemplo:

```
int x[10],y[10];
... *se generan los valores*
... X[10]={1,4,8,7,8,9,0,11,45,55}
... Y[10]={1,5,6,7,6,8,10,23,11,56}
```

podemos ver que el punto (8;6) se repite en dos ocaciones, hay alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Comment: El problema con los numeros aleatorios es que [se pueden
repetir los numeros](https://imgur.com/bwFWMqQ). Si no
quieres numeros repetidos puedes crear un array con una
secuencia numerica, y mezclarlo. De esa forma tendras numeros
unicos. Como tienes el tag de C++, puede que te convenga
investigar `std::shuffle`.

Comment: Se me ocurre hacer que tu secuencia generadora itere sobre los dos arrays conforme se van construyendo (llenando) y evalue si el elemento nuevo que generó ya existe y de ser así que entonces vuelva a generar uno nuevo.

Comment: En vez de generar dos grupos de  10 números aleatorios solo ten un grupo de 20 números aleatorios. Luego iteras estos 20 números con un índice que avance de dos en dos y dentro de bloque de iteracion le calculas random a qué índice del arreglo va el valor del array[i] y array[i-1] el índice si lo calculas generando dos números aleatorios rand()% 10

Comment: Un comentario más supongo que ejecutas  al iniciar el srand(). Otra alternativa es que lo hagas por rangos. Entre 0 y 20 para uno y el otro entra 20 y 30. Solo tendrías que cambiar el mod  y sumarle el inicio del rango.

Comment: Es C o C++. Si es C++ utiliza std::Set lugar de arrays e iteras hasta que el set este completo. El set te quita duplicados automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría ser algo así:

```
while (n < 10)
{
    int num1 = rand() % 100;
    int num2 = rand() % 100;
    bool existe = false;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] == num1 && y[i] == num2)
        {
            existe = true;
        }
    }
    if (existe == false)
    {
        x[n] = num1;
        y[n] = num2;
        n++;
    }
}
```